# HTML/CSS background image issues

Tags: html, css, angular, background-image

I am currently trying to test how to completely cover my Angular web page with an image background. I've looked into numerous examples online on how to get this to happen. This is what I've come up with in my .html and .css code:

```
<main class="mainPage">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
```

---

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  /*font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  min-height: 375px;
 }

 .mainPage {
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background: url(/assets/images/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
 }

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'm under the impression that this is how you are supposed to define your CSS if you want an image to cover the background of the screen. However, when I run this with npm start and traverse to localhost:4200, I am greeted with the following output:

[Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdAZF.jpg)

It appears that instead of the image covering the entire web page, it's only covering whatever is defined within it's HTML tag (e.g. the Angular logo image). Is there something wrong with my html or could it be something deeply rooted in my angular project elsewhere?

**SOLUTION:** As per codechick's response, I removed the height/width attributes from the html and main CSS tag definitions. Instead, I added:

```
.mainPage {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background: url(/assets/Wood.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: try to remove `fixed` from your background...

Comment: Why don't you try applying the background image to body instead of .mainPage ?

Comment: @MrLister My bad. Thanks!!

Comment: @Sean I can't reproduce the problem. [This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jo5j0tj/) has the background cover everything. So the problem must be with some of the code you're not showing. Can you make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well first you don't need the `body, html {height:100%}` then remove the height for `main` as well. use `height: 100vh` for `.mainPage` or the image container.

check my code here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYdNbe)

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you want to cover the web page with a background image, you will need to set a width as well as a height. Also, you might have some syntax wrong in your CSS.

```
.mainPage {
background-image: url("/assets/images/background.png");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Try this... Hope it works!

Comment: All elements in the OP's code have width and height set. In fact, if you try out their code, it works as desired. So there's not much we can say at this time.